# python encoding error at xlrd installation

Tags: python, encoding, installation, xlrd

I'm trying to install a xlrd 0.9.2 package on Python3.2 on windows 7. When I launch the setup.py install I receive encoding error: 'utf8' codec can't decode...

The module (licenses.py) where the installer stops has an encoding declaration:

`# -*- coding: cp1252 -*-`

but it seems the python is ignoring it. 
I was using Win cmd but also checked cygwin and have the same problem.

Few days ago I also had a problem with reading txt file that was in cp1252 even though I set this declaration in my script. I was using IDLE to run the script.
I'm not sure now if my python install has something missing or this is operating system issue

Answer (score 0):

Upgraded to Python 3.3 and the library got installed ok. Not sure if that's a problem with Python 3.2 or the instance I had.